# Next term in sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Came across these 3 sequences to find the next number denoted by '?' in a test yesterday and was unable to select the right answer from the options given

1. 1,6,19,54,151,426,?  - Options given are 1415, 1181, 1245, 1201, 1219
2. 20,40,50,110,115,215,? - Options given are 225, 217.67, 220, 218.33, 325
3. $\frac 14 $ , 1 ,  $\frac 3{10}$, $\frac 24$, $\frac 5{16}$, $\frac 37$, ? - Options given are $\frac 6{21}$ , $\frac 7{22}$ , $\frac 4{24}$ , $\frac 5{23}$ , $\frac 8{26}$

Comment: Which test? Could you be a bit more specific about the source?

Comment: @Randal'Thor it was an Online Assessment from a Trading firm as the 1st step of their application.

Comment: Looks like this should be three different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0/

> Initial thought:  Trading firm - Financial - especially consider exponentional behavior

1/

> A 'nice increasing' sequence
>  Looking at the bigger numbers that often show the trend best: I see approximately times 3; also in most answers
>  When using X[n+1] = 3X[n] the remainders are: 3 (6=3+3), 1 (19-18+1), -3, -11, -27
>  I did not see an immediate simple progression. Taking differences is often a good idea to try.
>  This gives the sequence -2, -4, -8, -16; clearly a power of 2.
>  X[n+1] = 3X[n] - 2^n + C fits for C=5
>  answer 1219

2/

> A sequence with alternating small and big increases -> try odd even subsequences.
>  20,50,115,? and 40,110,215
>  I did not recognize anything useful -> try differences.
>  20,10,60,5,100
>  Still thinking exponential; note the factors between successive differences: 1/2, 6, 1/12, 20
>  I immediately recognized the sequence 2,6,12,20.
>  Difference pattern: 1/(1x2), (2x3), 1/(3x4), (4x5)  --> 1/(5x6)
>  answer 215+100/(5x6) = 218.33.
>  In general, X[n] = X[n-1] + 100 ((n-2)*(n-1)) ^ k, where k = -1 if n is odd, and k = +1 if n is even.

3/

> A sequence with alternating small and big numbers -> try odd even subsequences.
>  1/4, 3/10, 5/16,? and 1, 2/4, 3/7
>  note the linearly increasing numbers, especially if one writes 1 = 1/1
>  1,3,5->7 and 4,10,16 ->22 gives as answer 7/22

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer:*

In part 3, the sequence is:
$\frac{1}{4}$, $1$, $\frac{3}{10}$,
$\frac{2}{4}$, $\frac{5}{16}$, $\frac{3}{7}$, ?

To solve this I will use two tricks.

My first trick is to

> split the sequence into two subsequences.  One subsequence will consist of the terms in the odd-numbered positions.  The other subsequence will consist of the terms in the even-numbered positions.

> The “odd” subsequence is:
>  $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{10}$, $\frac{5}{16}$, $\dots$
>
>  The pattern here is that the numerators are increasing by 2 and the denominators are increasing by 6.
>
>  Following this pattern the next odd-numbered term (and the answer to this puzzle) is $\frac{7}{22}$.

But to ensure that our answer is reasonable,

> let’s look at the “even” subsequence.
>
>  My second trick is to rewrite the second term of the original sequence as a fraction.
>
>  So the “even” subsequence is:
>  $\frac{1}{1}$, $\frac{2}{4}$, $\frac{3}{7}$, $\dots$
>
>  The pattern here is that the numerators are increasing by 1 and the denominators are increasing by 3.
>
>  So we have a reasonably simple explanation for **ALL** the terms of the entire original sequence and therefore we have confidence that our expected next term of $\frac{7}{22}$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is 1219.

Let u denote the sequence. `(u[0] = 1, u[1] = 6, ...)`

Then the pattern seems to be :

```
u[n] = u[n-1] * 3 - 2 ^ n + 5
```

For example :

```
u[4] = u[3] * 3 - 2 ^ 4 + 5
     = 54 * 3 - 16 + 5
     = 162 - 11
     = 151
```